# Fire and forget call request timeout value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Using the following code for fire and forget call, what should be the appropriate timeout value for a HTTP call to a remote service. I do not care about the response. But there are times in the day i am getting request timed out exception.

Exception -

> Exception: System.Net.WebException    Message: The request was
>   aborted: The operation has timed out.

Code-

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            o =>
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    request.KeepAlive = false;
                    request.Timeout = ????????;
                    var response = request.GetResponse();
                    response.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //logging
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why don't you simply ignore it?

Comment: I cannot have no timeout because i think the default timeout is 120 seconds and that is way too long and 100s of calls go through this a minute and i cannot have connections hanging in case of high latency.

Comment: Then set to 1 sec. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: trying to see if anyone has thought about this or done some experimentation to come up with an ideal number. Reducing it to 1 second might lead to canceling too many requests.

Comment: The "right" time would depend on your network, the web service response time, how long you can afford to have the request outstanding, ... . Perhaps a better question is should you be making a request if the response has no significance? Would using a TCP connection to write the "request", then close the connection, be sufficient?

Comment: Then don't ignore the response and measure the response times. That way you can find the average response time.

Comment: @MoXplod Why are you using a threadpool thread for IO bound work. Have you considered using `async/await` to generate a true asynchronous call?